# Extension working in layout pages but no longer working anywhere else

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, spfx, spfx-extensions

I've developped a custom Extension with SPFX. This custom extension performs a Search. I deployed it. Everything worked totally fine during 6 months.
And now, out of the blue, my extension is only visible in Site Content, no more in all the other pages.

**What i have :**

Custom extension created following the documentation. `gulp bundle --ship` generated temp files that I uploaded to a folder in a Library called CDN (which has been activated and recorded as a CDN origin).
gulp package-solution --ship generated my .appkg that i've uploaded to the appCatalog.

**The prompting errors :**

Normally, as in my Site Content,  in the dev Console, in the Network tab, I find my postquery, with all my query sent to SP.
Now, in my pages, when I check the dev console,

1. in the Network tab, my postquery is not appearing.
2. In the console tab, I have the following error : `"Uncaught (in promise) Error : Failed to create application customizer 'ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer.XXXXXXXX'.Error information is '***Extension failed to initialize for componentId "XXX".' "`

**What i tried :**

I tried a `gulp serve --nobrowser` to see if I had any issues. I have none, and my Extension is well displayed.

So, is it a CDN issue ? -even if I don't think so, because the extension works on _layouts pages.
Is it another issue ? How to debug that ?

Please help me, I am really stuck there.

Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Maybe it can relate to update of React in SharePoint Online CDNs. Try to update your local React to the same version and then run ``gulp serve`` again to see if the issue occurs. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/blogs/verification-guidance-sharepoint-online-moves-to-react-16/

Comment: Thanks @LukasNespor, But it "just" was Microsoft's update on the SharePoint DOM. I don't remember the details but it was a fregging class modification. My code was an injection of div elements through an extension, and to be injected, it was based on MS's class.. and it changed

Comment: hi @Gaelle how did you resolve this? im getting this same exact error where it only loads in the site contents or anywhere else just. not in the site pages

Comment: hi @PageF.P.T, sorry for the delay, I hope you found the solution, which was : modify the injection of the extension. It was based on a div class (because there was no div ID), and MS changed this class and the DOM structure. So change yours accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

Check which master page is applied to the site /_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx.
There are 2 master pages as in Site Master Page and System Master Page.
In your case System Master Page may be seattle, hence extension is working there.